# Usage of @IndexColumn results in a seq_num of 0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to make use @IndexColumn to set seq number of some data the user enters.  I am using Spring 2.5.6, JBoss 5.1 (JPA 1.0).

For my parent class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="material")
public class Material implements Serializable {
.
.
    /**
     * List of material attributes associated with the given material
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "material", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @IndexColumn(name="seq_number", base=0, nullable = false)
    private List<MaterialAttribute> materialAttributes;

    public void addMaterialAttribute(List<MaterialAttribute> attribs)
    {
        if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(attribs))
        {
            for(MaterialAttribute attrib : attribs)
            {
                attrib.setMaterial(this);
            }

            this.setMaterialAttributes(attribs);
        }
    }

}
```

For my child class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="material_attribute")
public class MaterialAttribute implements Serializable
{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "material_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable=false, nullable = true, unique = false)
    private Material material;

    @Column(name = "seq_number", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable = false)
    private int seqNumber;
}
```

For the service class

```
public void save(MaterialCommand pCmd)
{
    Material material = new Material(pCmd.getName());

    //convert from command object to entity object
    List<MaterialAttribute> attribs = new ArrayList<MaterialAttribute>();

    if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(pCmd.getAttribs()))
    {
        Iterator<MaterialAttributeCommand> iter = pCmd.getAttribs().iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            MaterialAttributeCommand attribCmd = (MaterialAttributeCommand) iter.next();

            MaterialAttribute attrib = new MaterialAttribute();
            attrib.setDisplayName(attribCmd.getDisplayName());
            attrib.setValidationType(attribCmd.getValidationType());

            attribs.add(attrib);
        }
    }

    material.addMaterialAttribute(attribs);

    this.getMaterialDAO().saveMaterial(material);
}
```

I am getting entries into the database but the seq_number is always zero, for every item in the collection.

I have to assume it is in the way that I am saving the data but I just do not see it.

---

**I have been able to solve the issue doing the following (removed the mappedBy):**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="material")
public class Material implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5083931681636496023L;

    @Column(name="name", length=50, nullable=false)
    private String mName;

    /**
     * List of material attributes associated with the given material
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    @IndexColumn(name="seq_number", base=0)
    @JoinColumn(name="material_id",nullable=false)
    private List<MaterialAttribute> materialAttributes;



@Entity
@Table(name="material_attribute")
public class MaterialAttribute implements Serializable
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -196083650806575093L;

    /**
     * identifies the material that these attributes are associated with
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "material_id", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable = true, unique = false)
    private Material material;

    @Column(name = "seq_number", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int seqNumber;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mapping a ***bidirectional*** indexed List with Hibernate  is a bit tricky but is covered in the section [2.4.6.2.1. Bidirectional association with indexed collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype-indexbidir) of the documentation (bold is mine):

> #### [2.4.6.2.1. Bidirectional association with indexed collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype-indexbidir)
>
> A bidirectional association where one
>   end is an indexed collection (ie.
>   represented as a `@OrderColumn`, or as
>   a `Map`) requires special
>   consideration. **If a property on the
>   associated class explicitly maps the
>   indexed value, the use of `mappedBy`
>   is permitted**:
>
> ```
> @Entity
> public class Parent {
>     @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
>     @OrderColumn(name="order")
>     private List<Child> children;
>     ...
> }
>
> @Entity
> public class Child {
>     ...
>     //the index column is mapped as a property in the associated entity
>     @Column(name="order")
>     private int order;
>
>     @ManyToOne
>     @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", nullable=false)
>     private Parent parent;
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> But, if there is no such property on
>   the child class, **we can't think of
>   the association as truly
>   bidirectional** (there is information
>   available at one end of the
>   association that is not available at
>   the other end: the index). In this
>   case, we can't map the collection as
>   `mappedBy`. Instead, we could use the
>   following mapping:
>
> ```
> @Entity
> public class Parent {
>     @OneToMany
>     @OrderColumn(name="order")
>     @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", nullable=false)
>     private List<Child> children;
>     ...
> }
>
> @Entity    
> public class Child {    
>     ...
>     @ManyToOne
>     @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
>     private Parent parent;
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> Note that in this mapping, **the
>   collection-valued end of the
>   association is responsible for
>   updating the foreign key**.

Actually, the second mapping is precisely how to map a bidirectional one to many with the **one-to-many side as the owning side**. While this is possible, you need to be aware that this kind of mapping will produce under optimized SQL as stated in the section about [2.2.5.3.1.1. Bidirectional](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1591) [One-to-many] relations:

> To map a bidirectional one to many,
>   with the one-to-many side as the
>   owning side, you have to remove the
>   `mappedBy` element and set the many to
>   one `@JoinColumn` as `insertable` and
>   `updatable` to `false`. **This solution is
>   not optimized and will produce some
>   additional UPDATE statements.**

To sum up, if mapping the index column as a property of the target entity is not a concern, this would be my recommendation (i.e. the first mapping).

#### References

- Hibernate Annotations 3.4 Reference Guide

  - [2.2.5.3.1.1. Bidirectional](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1591) [One-to-many]
  - [2.4.6.2.1. Bidirectional association with indexed collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype-indexbidir)