# JPA (Hibernate) creating ordered one to many relationship with List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I'm trying to have bi-directional relationship using JPA 2 (with Hibernate) with ordered many side (using List).

Based on problems reported with `@OneToMany(mappedBy` on:
[JPA 2.0 @OrderColumn annotation in Hibernate 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956171/jpa-2-0-ordercolumn-annotation-in-hibernate-3-5)
and
https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5732

I tried different approach, proposed on:
http://josian.wordpress.com/2006/09/09/hibernate-annotations-bidirectional-one-to-many/

However when persisting data I'm getting exception.

Consider following entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Schedule implements Serializable {
    private List<Presentation> presentations;
    private String name = null;

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn (name = "SCHEDULE_NAME")
    @IndexColumn(name = "PRESENTATION_POSITION")
    public List<Presentation> getPresentations() {
        return presentations;
    }

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Index(name = "ScheduleNameIdx")
    @Column(name = "SCHEDULE_NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

...
}

@Entity
public class Presentation implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Schedule schedule;

    ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Index(name = "PresentationIdIdx")
    @Column(name = "PRESENTATION_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="SCHEDULE_NAME", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    public Schedule getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }
...
}
```

Exception I get is:

```
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] DEBUG o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - could not insert: [com.google.code.yourpresenter.entity.Presentation] [insert into Presentation (PRESENTATION_ID, bgImage_id, media_id, name, song_id) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10066 table: PRESENTATION column: SCHEDULE_NAME
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2345) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2852) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3MergeEventListener.java:62) [hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:415) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:341) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:258) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:877) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:859) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$6.cascade(CascadingAction.java:279) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:630) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:490) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855) [hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:686) [hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_15]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240) [spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy34.merge(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.service.ScheduleServiceImpl.persist(ScheduleServiceImpl.java:71) [classes/:na]
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.service.ScheduleServiceImpl.addPresentation(ScheduleServiceImpl.java:122) [classes/:na]
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.service.ScheduleServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$52d414d3.invoke(<generated>) [cglib-2.2.2.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [cglib-2.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689) [spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) [spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) [spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622) [spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.service.ScheduleServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9dfe2fc9.addPresentation(<generated>) [cglib-2.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.view.ScheduleView.dropped(ScheduleView.java:154) [classes/:na]
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.view.ScheduleView.dropped(ScheduleView.java:92) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_15]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187) [jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20091210.jar:na]
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297) [jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20091210.jar:na]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.richfaces.event.MethodExpressionDropListener.processDrop(MethodExpressionDropListener.java:45) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.richfaces.event.DropEvent.processListener(DropEvent.java:69) [richfaces-components-api-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769) [jsf-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0-FCS]
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractDropTarget.broadcast(AbstractDropTarget.java:123) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jsf-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0-FCS]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) [jsf-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409) [jsf-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0-FCS]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.filter.ScheduleSelectedFilter.doFilter(ScheduleSelectedFilter.java:47) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410) [jetty-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582) [jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:6.1.26]
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10066 table: PRESENTATION column: SCHEDULE_NAME
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.hsqldb.Table.enforceRowConstraints(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertRowSet(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] WARN  o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: -10, SQLState: 23502
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] ERROR o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10066 table: PRESENTATION column: SCHEDULE_NAME
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] DEBUG o.h.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl - mark transaction for rollback
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@b840d2]
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - rollback
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - rolled back JDBC Connection
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@b840d2] after transaction
07:39:43.265 [12937429@qtp-9708927-7] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
19.8.2012 7:39:43 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: /presenter/presenter.xhtml @302,44 dropListener="#{scheduleView.dropped}": org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert: [com.google.code.yourpresenter.entity.Presentation]; SQL [insert into Presentation (PRESENTATION_ID, bgImage_id, media_id, name, song_id) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.google.code.yourpresenter.entity.Presentation]
javax.el.ELException: /presenter/presenter.xhtml @302,44 dropListener="#{scheduleView.dropped}": org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert: [com.google.code.yourpresenter.entity.Presentation]; SQL [insert into Presentation (PRESENTATION_ID, bgImage_id, media_id, name, song_id) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.google.code.yourpresenter.entity.Presentation]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at org.richfaces.event.MethodExpressionDropListener.processDrop(MethodExpressionDropListener.java:45)
    at org.richfaces.event.DropEvent.processListener(DropEvent.java:69)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractDropTarget.broadcast(AbstractDropTarget.java:123)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.filter.ScheduleSelectedFilter.doFilter(ScheduleSelectedFilter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert: [com.google.code.yourpresenter.entity.Presentation]; SQL [insert into Presentation (PRESENTATION_ID, bgImage_id, media_id, name, song_id) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.google.code.yourpresenter.entity.Presentation]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:641)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.service.ScheduleServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9dfe2fc9.addPresentation(<generated>)
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.view.ScheduleView.dropped(ScheduleView.java:154)
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.view.ScheduleView.dropped(ScheduleView.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.google.code.yourpresenter.entity.Presentation]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2345)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2852)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3MergeEventListener.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:859)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$6.cascade(CascadingAction.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:630)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:686)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at $Proxy34.merge(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.service.ScheduleServiceImpl.persist(ScheduleServiceImpl.java:71)
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.service.ScheduleServiceImpl.addPresentation(ScheduleServiceImpl.java:122)
    at com.google.code.yourpresenter.service.ScheduleServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$52d414d3.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10066 table: PRESENTATION column: SCHEDULE_NAME
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10066 table: PRESENTATION column: SCHEDULE_NAME
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.enforceRowConstraints(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertRowSet(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 96 more
```

Comment: OK guys, thanks a lot for the support, finally I came to working implementation, the solution I've found at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054570/usage-of-indexcolumn-results-in-a-seq-num-of-0 I plan to update my question to provide the fixed information, thanks a lot for all your support

Answer (score 0):

Remove @NotNull. Not key field don't allowed null values. Consider an input data.

Comment: thanks for reply. I removed @NotNull, but that didn't help, I still have the same error. What did you mean with "Consider an input data"?

Comment: DB schema is created for me automatically on application startup => no update required.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you specified `updatable = false, insertable = false` in the `Presentation` to `Schedule` mapping?

Of course this value needs to be insertable and updatable to maintain the relationship. Try removing this and you should see the SQL change when you attempt the insert.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, however these were present due to fact, that I needed to reverse the relationship, to make sure the collection-valued end of the association is responsible for updating the foreign key (the owning side is the Schedule), as explained on: https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/entity-hibspec-collection-extratype-indexbidir.html

Answer (score 0):

For your persist strategy, hibernate will insert record to 'Presentation' table first and then update its 'schedule_id', but you set the schedule_id not null，so the insert will fail.

One solution is remove the 'not null' constraint。

The second solution is redesign the relationship configuration，let hibernate only execute one insert sentence（include the 'schedule_id'), don't need the updating

Answer (score 0):

In your Presentation entity, change getSchedule()'s attributes insertable and updateble to **true**. See below;

```
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name="SCHEDULE_NAME", nullable =false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
   public Schedule getSchedule() {
      return schedule;
   }
```

Comment: similar solution was proposed by milkplusvellocet, but as I wrote him, that doesn't solve the problem for me